# Is there a fan in the Late 2013 iMac?

Tags: imac

Is there a fan in the [Late 2013 iMac](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/imac/specs/imac-core-i5-3.2-27-inch-aluminum-late-2013-specs.html)? The model identifier for this iMac is `iMac14,2`.

(Note I am not asking whether you can *hear* the fan. I want to know if a fan *is present* in the Late 2013 iMacs at all.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, there is one fan in both Late 2013 iMacs ([21,5"](https://ifixit.com/Teardown/iMac+Intel+21.5-Inch+EMC+2638+Teardown/17829) & [27"](https://ifixit.com/Teardown/iMac+Intel+27-Inch+EMC+2639+Teardown/17828)).